# Javascript Click Button Insert Text

Tags: javascript, html

Based on the current cursor/textbox selected , when the user clicks a button/character I would like the character to be inserted where the cursor is.

Here is a js fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YD6PL/32/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".buttons").click(function () {
        var cntrl = $(this).html();
        $("#txt-area1").append(cntrl);//not sure what to use here to "know" where cursor currently is
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="txt-area1" readonly></textarea>
<textarea id="txt-area2" readonly></textarea>
<textarea id="txt-area3" readonly></textarea>
<textarea id="txt-area4" readonly></textarea>
<div>
<button class="buttons">á</button>
<button class="buttons">é</button>
<button class="buttons">í</button>
<button class="buttons">ó</button>
<button class="buttons">ú</button>
<button class="buttons">ñ</button>
<button class="buttons">ü</button>
</div>
```

How can I make the above "know" which of the multiple text boxes is selected and insert the character only into this box?

Comment: How about when an element is focused append a class `active`, when it losses focus remove that class. Then You can append the text box with the `active` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a class of `active` to a clicked textarea and select that active textarea when you append.

```
$('textarea').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active')
});

$(".buttons").click(function () {
    var cntrl = $(this).html();
    $('textarea.active').append(cntrl);
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/YD6PL/33/)

Comment: What a quick answer. I had the same idea but wow, you thought of it and implemented as fast as I just thought about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use focus event on textarea:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var selected = undefined;

    $('textarea').on('focus', function(){
        selected = $(this)
    })

    $(".buttons").click(function () {
        if(selected) {
            var cntrl = $(this).html();
            selected.append(cntrl);
        }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/YD6PL/35/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentDiv;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".buttons").click(function (el) {
        var cntrl = $(this).html();

        $(currentDiv).append(cntrl);
    });
});

$("#parent").click(function(e) {
    currentDiv = e.target
});
```

Comment: Could you improve your answer by explaining what you fixed?